# Group template in Header.xsl not working

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

I have the following template in Header.xsl file:

```
<xsl:template name="MyList" match="*[@GroupStyle='MyList']" mode="header">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="columns large-4 centered">
          ID
      </div>
      <div class="columns large-4">
          Form Name
      </div>
      <div class="columns large-4">
          Submitter Name
      </div>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

When I apply it to on Content Query Web Part, it makes no difference on UI.

How to make the CQWP render the desired header row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates defined with `mode="header"` attribute (file `Header.xsl`) are invoked only when the **Grouping** is enabled for CQWP (see picture below)

[image]